# How to download and set high-quality voices in Android text-to-speech in MIUI 14?

Tags: miui, text-to-speech

The option to download and set high-quality voices in Android text-to-speech is not available in MIUI 14. Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While certain voice are available for downloading offline from the corresponding menu under **Settings** > **System** > **Languages & Input** > **Text-to-Speech output**, high quality voices are only available online and won't work without an internet connection.